# use of бы here with надо

Tags: грамматика

i always thought бы should be used with verbs in the past tense. 
Example: Я тебя бы сказал. I should have told you.

but the passage below it's used like this:
надо бы рассказать...

На фоне трагедии Фауста это персонаж скорее малозначительный, чем загадочный, однако справедливости ради надо бы рассказать и о нем.

Comment: Я теб**е** бы сказал, (not теб**я**) and it means "*I would have told you*" or "*I would tell you*", not "I should have"

Comment: as Alex_ander has noted this expression can also be worded as ***надо БЫЛО бы рассказать*** so you get the past tense in БЫЛО

Comment: i wonder if надо бы is actually надо есть бы or something with to be in present

Comment: @Arioch i feel it's actually projected into the future, but since we unfortunately can't say ***надо будет бы*** we're only relegated to the past tense, in fact ***надо бы рассказать*** is also to an extent synonymous to ***надо будет рассказать***

Comment: I think it is only projected in a way how present tense is often used to describe settled future. "I am going to buy car tomorrow", "Я иду в школу завтра", etc. So it is already today and now w.r.t. "надо", while the action itself is indeed for the future, the "it is required" state is here already. We talk about immediately *present need* to *do* something in the *future*.

Comment: It's very important to understand that _бы_ is **not** used with the past tense verbs, it's just a mere coincidence that the verb form looks exactly like the past tense. When you say it's the past tense, it sounds just the same way as if you said that "Freeze!" is the present tense verb.

Comment: @YellowSky then what is it? Вчера нам было весело. Вчера нам было нужно сходить за хлебом. Вчера нам было надо сходить за хлебом. Sounds like a past.

Comment: @Arioch - And this is future: "Надо было бы тебе это завтра рассказать, но так и быть, расскажу сегодня."

Comment: Future in the past. Diving to the prior time to look from there to the future. "Вчера нам было весело завтра тебе рассказывать", ага.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this usage **(надо) бы** expresses the author's *hesitation*, as if the idea of writing about something else came up at the last moment and it's unclear yet if that material should be placed in the same section of the book, how detailed it should be, etc.

If the author just wanted to mention that opportunity without writing about it at all, they could write **(надо) было бы** instead and then explain why the idea was abandoned.